# apply css on menu item click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little test application here...
http://jsfiddle.net/poppypoop/LMCC2/

I was wondering how I would accomplish the same functionality with angular js. Ultimately adding the 'active' class to the selected menu item while applying the name to the header below. In the fiddle I've done it with jquery, but now I'm wondering how this would be accomplished through angularjs

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
function ctrl($scope, Data)
{

}
```

Would it be best to do it in a directive or controller?

Comment: To "compare" jQuery and angular I recommend taking a quick look at [link link](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-application-wiring-jquery-vs-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to be setting the class and modifying the HTML within angular at all. Instead, the angular model should represent the data of your application and use databinding to change view-related properties such as classes, etc.

In your case, the scope could have a list of menu items and a property that holds the currently active item. And when a menu item is clicked on, the active item changes. All the changes in the view are handled by angular databinding...

```
$scope.items = ['Home', 'Tickets', 'Direct Deposit', 'activity',
                'Pay Rate Inquiry', 'Templates'];
$scope.activeItem = 'Home';
$scope.setActive = function (activeItem) {
    $scope.activeItem = activeItem;
};
```

View

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-ul" class="nav">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <a ng-class="{ active: item === selectedItem }" href="#" 
             ng-click="setActive(item)">{{ item }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav-selection">
    <span>{{ activeItem }}</span>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xx7KF/

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can use ng-class for adding a class with a boolean condition:

[AngularJS - ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

You can bind the class to a boolean var in your scope, and when you click on the button, update it with the value you need.